# Compare columns between two different excel files (python, pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

i want to compare columns and rows of two different excel files. i want to compare the values of "Category 2" in file1 to "Group" list in file2. if the value of file2 doesn't exist in file1, delete the row from file2. i have been looking around and tried some different things but can't find anything specific to what i'm trying to do. if necessary, i can remove headings like "All Lists" and "List X" from file1, but in terms of comparing, i don't really know how to move forward. i'd appreciate any help or pointers or know if this is even possible. thank you

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1', 'Table 3')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

# difference = df1[df1!=df2]
# print(df1.equals(df2))

print(df1['Category 2']).where(df1['Courses']) == df2['Group']
```

file1

```
All Lists
Category 1  Category 2  Category 3  Category 4  Category 5  Category 6                   
List 1                  
            element1        x   
            element2        x   
            element3        x   
            element4        x   
            element5        x   
List 2                  
            card1           x   
            card2           x   
            card3           x   
            card4           x   
            card5           x   
List 3                  
            box1            x   
            box2            x   
            box3            x   
            box4            x   
            box5            x
```

file2

```
Group   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2    A           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  B           $          $           $           $                      $
card3       C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4        D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3    E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1        F           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  B           $          $           $           $                      $
notElement  C           $          $           $           $                      $             
card7       D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4    E           $          $           $           $                      $
```

desired output:

```
Group   Manager     quarter1    quarter2    quarter3    quarter4                total
element2    A           $          $           $           $                      $
card3       C           $          $           $           $                      $
box4        D           $          $           $           $                      $
element3    E           $          $           $           $                      $
box1        F           $          $           $           $                      $
card7       D           $          $           $           $                      $
element4    E           $          $           $           $                      $
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Series.isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas-series-isin) to check whether elements in `df2["Group"]` are contained in `df1["Category_2"]`, this returns a `True/False` series that when applied with `index` can by used to drop unwanted rows (`df2.drop(df2[notCateg].index)`)

```
df1 = pd.read_excel('file1', 'Table 3')
df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')

notCateg = ~df2["Group"].isin(df1["Category_2"])
df2 = df2.drop(df2[notCateg].index)
df2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(df2)
```

```
      Group Manager quarter1 quarter2 quarter3 quarter4 total
0  element2       A        $        $        $        $     $
1     card3       C        $        $        $        $     $
2      box4       D        $        $        $        $     $
3  element3       E        $        $        $        $     $
4      box1       F        $        $        $        $     $
5  element4       E        $        $        $        $     $
```